# Baking Textures with Python: Why there is no loading bar and blender kind of freezes

Tags: texturing, interface, texture-baking

So, Let me Elaborate, When I try to bake normal map or any other map with blender default baker, we get a loading bar which shows the progress of the map like in the image,[image]
I want to automate doing this with a script like here simple one.

```
import bpy
bpy.ops.object.bake(type = 'NORMAL')
```

But when I run the script although it does work, it doesn't show the loading box in bottom as by pressing bake button shows.
Any way to make the loading box appear when I run script too?[image]

Comment: What does the console says? Have you tried also to call the object.bake from the PythonConsole? If there was no problem, you should see "{'FINISHED'}" as output.

Comment: It works both ways either I use the python script or default bake button, My question is why it doesn't show a progress bar when I run bake function with script.

Comment: Ah, Ok. Then you need to call the operator with the invoke_default flag: ```bpy.ops.object.bake('INVOKE_DEFAULT')```.
See here in the 'Execution Context' section: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.html

Comment: Thank you! That works as intended, Appreciate that! Apart from this do u have any recommendation for Blender Scripting TUts or courses? I do have programming background but I don't know how to figure out to use in Blender with python..

Comment: If you have programming knowledge, reading the API docs is the best you can find. The templates are usefull, and looking at other addons might help. Tutorials usually don't go deep enough to let you create anything apart from what the tutorial teaches.

Comment: Thank you, I will focus on that, then :)